# Not able to set border to a column - phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I am using **PhpExcel** for my application.
When I use this below code to set border for an individual cell, it works fine. But when I use it for all cells in a column ('A') it throws the below error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rat\xls-class\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on line 1219

Defining border style:

```
$border_style= array('borders' => array('right' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN)));
```

Applying to all cells in column 'A':

```
$sheet->getStyle("A")->applyFromArray($border_style);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply a style to a column, only to an individual cell or to a range of cells

```
$sheet->getStyle("A1:A65535")->applyFromArray($border_style);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker. It works. But applying to a row works well, why not columns

Comment: I don't have an answer to that, beside the fact that it shouldn't work for rows either.... possibly some loose-typing issue with side effects?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a border on cells or cell range, for example the following code worked
for me well:

```
 public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
{
    $sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();

    $sheet->getStyle('A4:Z5')->applyFromArray([
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => ['argb' => '000000'],
            ],
        ],
 ]);

}
```

Just implement the function in your export class.